# Short proof of the structure of the solution of linear differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Do you have a short proof for the structure of the solution for the linear differential equation : 
$$
ay'' + by' + cy = 0
$$
where $a,b$ complexe numbers.

Because I only found annoying one, I can't do the proof again quickly.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: You need to give more details: what's the domain? Which proof do you not like and why?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $a\ne 0$, let $\varphi_0,\varphi_1$ the solutions of the IVPs
$$
ax''+bx'+cx=0, \quad x(0)=1, \,\,x'(0)=0,
$$
and
$$
ax''+bx'+cx=0, \quad x(0)=0, \,\,x'(0)=1,
$$
respectively. If $\psi$ is an arbitrary solution of $ax''+bx'+cx=0$, then $\psi$ satisfies the IVP
$$
ax''+bx'+cx=0, \quad x(0)=\psi(0), \,\,x'(0)=\psi'(0). \tag{1}
$$
But $\psi(0)\varphi_0(t)+\psi'(0)\varphi_1(t)$ also satisfies $(1)$,
and since $(1)$ enjoys uniqueness, then $\psi(t)=\psi(0)\varphi_0(t)+\psi'(0)\varphi_1(t)$.

Hence the general solution of $ax''+bx'+cx$ is of the form
$\xi_0\varphi_0+\xi_1\varphi_1$.

Comment: Well of course it's trivial if you _assume_ uniqueness...